# csv file showing ... instead of whole data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

**Im trying to look at a csv file with this code:**

```
import pandas as pd    
import numpy as np    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("/Users/tristanshah/Desktop/trainingandtestdata/training.1600000.processed.noemoticon.csv", header=None, names=['sentiment', 'id', 'date', 'query_string', 'user', 'text'], encoding='ISO-8859-1')

print(df.head())
```

**If I run this it returns:**

```
  ...
0 ...
1 ...
2 ...
3 ...
4 ...
```

[5 rows x 6 columns]

**how do I show the whole dataframe?**

Comment: instead of print(df.head()) use print(df)

Comment: `df.head()` only shows the first 5 rows just `print(df)`

Comment: when I print(df) it prints all 1600000 rows but only the first column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is wondering here is the fix

```
pandas.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pandas.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pandas.set_option('display.width', None)
```

include this and it removes limits to the dataframe

Answer (score -1):

df.head() only displays the summary of your given data set. if you want info about all rows and columns try df.info()

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it gave me all the column names as a list. But is there a way to display all the columns of the data frame as a table though?

Comment: you could just type in print(df) . if you are using anaconda navigator it displays the first few columns followed by dotted representation